# Xamarin Forms Labs: NullReferenceException when calling ViewFactory.CreatePage

Tags: xamarin, ninject, xamarin.forms

I am having a problem when trying to use the Xamarin.Forms.Labs(v1.2.0) ViewFactory.CreatePage method.

This is my shared forms App.cs:

```cs
public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
        ViewFactory.Register<JobsView, JobsViewModel>();

        return new NavigationPage(ViewFactory.CreatePage<JobsViewModel>());
    }
```

Top of my JobsViewModel:

```cs
[ViewType(typeof(JobsView))]
public class JobsViewModel : Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Mvvm.ViewModel
{
```

My view:

```cs
public partial class JobsView : Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Mvvm.BaseView
{
    public JobsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new JobsViewModel();
    }
```

This is my IoC setup inside App.xaml.cs of my Windows Phone 8.0 project:

```cs
var app = new XFormsAppWP();
            app.Init(this);

var resolverContainer = new NinjectContainer();
        resolverContainer.Register<IDevice>(t => WindowsPhoneDevice.CurrentDevice)
            .Register<IDisplay>(t => t.Resolve<IDevice>().Display)
            .Register<IDependencyContainer>(t => resolverContainer)
            .Register<IXFormsApp>(app);

Resolver.SetResolver(resolverContainer.GetResolver());
```

When calling `ViewFactory.CreatePage<JobsViewModel>()`, I get the following error:

```cs
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Ninject.Planning.Bindings.BindingConfiguration.GetProvider(IContext context)
   at Ninject.Planning.Bindings.Binding.GetProvider(IContext context)
   at Ninject.Infrastructure.Introspection.FormatExtensionsEx.Format(IBinding binding, IContext context)
   at Ninject.KernelBase.<Resolve>b__a(<>f__AnonymousType0`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier8)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request, Boolean handleMissingBindings)
   at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request)
   at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.GetResolutionIterator(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, Func`2 constraint, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Boolean isOptional, Boolean isUnique)
   at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T](IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Services.Ninject.NinjectResolver.Resolve[T]()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Services.Resolver.Resolve[T]()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Mvvm.ViewFactory.CreatePage[TViewModel](Action`2 initialiser)
   at SharedForms.App.GetMainPage()
   at Windows.Phone.MainPage..ctor()
```

Any help on how to fix/debug further appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a bug on Ninject rather than XLabs side. Ninject doesn't seem to like to register JobsViewModel as JobsViewModel. Trying to resolve it will throw the null reference exception. I tested with both SimpleContainer and TinyIoc but if you can confirm that other Ioc resolver works as expected I would appreciate it.

Comment: @SKall I have tried the same code with TinyIoC and can confirm that it now works correctly.